# Cannot play audio cds on linux: "Buffer I/O error on device sr0"

Tags: linux, playback, compact-disc, audio-cd

I got a Thinkpad R61 with a Matshita drive and, as the title says, I cannot play audio CDs. After inserted a CD, syslog shows:

```
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : 0x5 [current]
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Info fld=0x0
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] ASC=0x64 ASCQ=0x0
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 2
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 3
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 4
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 5
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 6
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 7
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 8
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 9
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] Sense Key : 0x5 [current]
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: Info fld=0x0
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] ASC=0x64 ASCQ=0x0
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: sr 3:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
Aug 26 10:39:36 localhost kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
```

I did't know if this is an hardware issue so I tried an external dvd drive but I got the same errors.
To play CDs I tried different programs: xmms2, cdcd, mplayer and sound-juicer and different cds (all original if this matter) but without luck.

I also tried a different kernel version, actually I'm using a custom one, using a debian precompiled ones (package linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64) but again without luck.

Here a relevant kernel configuration:

```
#
# SCSI device support
#
CONFIG_SCSI_MOD=y
# CONFIG_RAID_ATTRS is not set
CONFIG_SCSI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DMA=y
# CONFIG_SCSI_TGT is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_NETLINK is not set
CONFIG_SCSI_PROC_FS=y

#
# SCSI support type (disk, tape, CD-ROM)
#
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD=y
# CONFIG_CHR_DEV_ST is not set
# CONFIG_CHR_DEV_OSST is not set
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SR=y
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SR_VENDOR is not set
CONFIG_CHR_DEV_SG=y
# CONFIG_CHR_DEV_SCH is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_MULTI_LUN is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_CONSTANTS is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_LOGGING is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_SCAN_ASYNC is not set
CONFIG_SCSI_WAIT_SCAN=m

#
# SCSI Transports
#
# CONFIG_SCSI_SPI_ATTRS is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_FC_ATTRS is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_ISCSI_ATTRS is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_SAS_ATTRS is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_SAS_LIBSAS is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_SRP_ATTRS is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_LOWLEVEL is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_DH is not set
# CONFIG_SCSI_OSD_INITIATOR is not set
CONFIG_ATA=y
# CONFIG_ATA_NONSTANDARD is not set
# CONFIG_ATA_VERBOSE_ERROR is not set
CONFIG_ATA_ACPI=y
# CONFIG_SATA_PMP is not set
CONFIG_SATA_AHCI=y
# CONFIG_SATA_SIL24 is not set
CONFIG_ATA_SFF=y
# CONFIG_SATA_SVW is not set
CONFIG_ATA_PIIX=y
```

Here the output of `hdparm -i /dev/sr0`:

```
/dev/sr0:

 Model=MATSHITADVD-RAM UJ-850, FwRev=RB11, SerialNo=HB5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Debian bug hits you! A Debian bug hits you! A Debian bug hits you! You die... do you want your possessions identified? (y/n)

Ahem.

It seems you have hit an [actual Debian bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=591290). In short, the udev rules are a bit messed up and thus only data-CDs are supported out of the box.

The good news is that the bug should now be fixed. Have you run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` lately?

Comment: Installing udev 0.161 helped me to remove the errors and now I can play audio-cds with the precompiled Debian kernel, but not with my own configuration. I cannot understand what modules i need, lshw-gtk show the ide interface (driver ata-piix) but this is not enough. What others modules do i need?

Comment: Do you have ATAPI support enabled?

Comment: The problem was simpler that i can expect, all those programs looks at /dev/cdrom while i have /dev/cdrom1. Those errors bring me in the wrong direction. Thanks Janne

Comment: You're welcome! :) The errors can sometimes be really confusing.